# How do you reset firefox without losing your bookmarks/logins?

Tags: login, firefox, malware, bookmarks

I've been getting these black-background text popups in the upper right corner when I have firefox running (they appear even when minimized) and when I click on them it takes me to pages. I'm not sure why this happens. I have 2 Extensions (Image Search Options from saucenao.com and https://github.com/bijij/ViewImage ) and 2 Plugins (OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc and Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google Inc.) so I don't know if any of these might have a reputation. They vanish on their own so it's hard to get a screenshot in time.

What seemed to fix it last time was:

> delete your ~/.mozilla folder and ./config/mozilla/  and restart FF
>   you just lose all plugins/malware/data
>   this ~/. is just user data

This worked but I lost my bookmarks and logins so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to back that up ahead of time so I can add it back after deleting these folders.

Answer (score 1):

Click the *Bookmarks* button (underlined **☆**) in the top right corner and select *Show All Bookmarks* to open the **Library** window. From the toolbar on the Library window, click *Import and Backup* and choose *Export Bookmarks to HTML...*. In the window that opens, choose a location to save the file, which is named bookmarks.html by default and click the *Save* button.

To import the saved bookmarks back into Firefox follow the same navigation as above only select *Import Bookmarks from HTML...* instead of *Export Bookmarks to HTML...*. Don't delete the bookmarks.html file even after you are finished using it, because it is also useful for importing your Firefox bookmarks into other web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try [refreshing Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) instead of deleting its config files.